# Is the set of all polynomial closed in the $ C[a,b] $ space?

Tags: general-topology

Is the set of all polynomial closed in the  $ C[a,b] $ space ?

Comment: For what topology?

Comment: C[a, b] means? Set of all continuos function on [a, b]?

Comment: @Bernard Yes good question Sir. +1.

Comment: Usually this is not true, because you can take the sequence of polynomials $1$, $1 + x$, $1 + x + x^2/2$, $1 + x + x^2/2 + x^3/3!$, ...., which should converge to $e^x$, which is not a polynomial. But of course, it depends on what norm/topology you have in mind.

Comment: @AvinashN  Yes . @Bernard , I don`t know what topology,I only know space

Comment: If you don't know what topology, in which sense do you mean "closed" ?

Comment: @AwesomeMan Look at the Joppy's answer. He gave a perfect counter example. Thus your set is not closed.

Comment: @ Fred,  i mean closed set

Comment: @AvinashN, I vote for it/ Thanks for all answers

Comment: @AwesomeMan But topology is very important. How to define a topology on set of continuous functions?? Depends on a chosen topology the answer may vary.

Comment: @AvinashN, Can you give me an example of topologies and definition. because, the name of thesis is may be different in ukrainian and in english. And I never working with topologies. I work with sets, and spaces, and similar things.
This is the question from the book, and there just only question what I write in title of my question. Thanks!

Comment: @AwesomeMan I am also not familiar with this one. So that I have asked the reference of these concepts to Bernard. See the comment of Bernard's answer. His answer really helpful for us. And thank you for asking this question. I got new ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If we have the norm $||f||:= \max\{|f(x)|: x \in [a,b]\}$ on $C[a,b]$ and if we denote by $P$ the set of all poynomials, then $P$ is a subspace of $C[a,b]$ with

$$\overline{P}=C[a,b].$$

This is the Approximation Theorem of Weierstraß

$\overline{P}$ denotes the closure of $P$ in $(C[a,b],||*||) $ .

Answer (score 2):

On the contrary, for the $\mathcal C^\infty$ norm (uniform convergence norm), *Stone-Weierstrass' theorem* asserts the set of polynomial functions is *dense* in $\mathcal C \bigl([a,b]\bigr)$.

Comment: Sir, Can you suggest any links or books for understanding better these concepts? Your answer is really interesting.